# Connection failed to SQL Server Express using user with SQL Server authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, database-connection, connection-string

I have IIS and SQL Server Express on the same machine. After deployment of web site to this environment I get this error:

> Cannot open database "MyDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\USER'.

Here are my connection strings where I set SQL Server user

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myCS1" 
         connectionString="data source=172.20.3.20\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDB;user id=SomeUser;password=SomeUser###;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="myCS2" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/CLModel.csdl|res://*/CLModel.ssdl|res://*/CLModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=172.20.3.20\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=myDB;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomeUser###;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I want to use SQL Server user for connection to the database but not AppPool user.

I specified login and password but it seems that this info is not taken in account and in error message I still see IIS user but not sql.

What I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you specify **both** - explicit user id and password, **and** `Integrated Security=True` - in your `myCS1` connection string:

```
data source=172.20.3.20\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDB;
  user id=SomeUser;password=SomeUser###;integrated security=True;
```

In this case, the **integrated security** wins over your user - you need to specify **only** the user id and password and get rid of the integrated security - so use this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myCS1" 
         connectionString="data source=172.20.3.20\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MyDB;user id=SomeUser;password=SomeUser###;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="myCS2" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/CLModel.csdl|res://*/CLModel.ssdl|res://*/CLModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=172.20.3.20\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=myDB;persist security info=True;user id=SomeUser;password=SomeUser###;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```